# How can I get my app to wait for a permission request to complete?

Tags: swift, grand-central-dispatch

My updated code is below, added a semaphore, and the app still blows through the AVCaptureDevice.authorizationStatus part and keeps running.

However, if I declare the semaphore with 0, then the first semaphore.wait() is successful, and the program freezes because the userAlert permission box never pops up.

So am having a tough time figuring out what the issue is here.

```
print ("going in...")
let semaphore = DispatchSemaphore(value: 1 )
DispatchQueue.global(qos: .userInitiated).async {
    let mediaAuthorizationStatus = AVCaptureDevice.authorizationStatus(for: .audio)
    switch mediaAuthorizationStatus {
        case .denied:
            print (".denied")
        case .authorized:
            print ("authorized")
        case .restricted:
            print ("restricted")
        case .notDetermined:
            print("Need to ask user")
        semaphore.wait()
                AVCaptureDevice.requestAccess(for: .audio, completionHandler: { (granted: Bool) in
                    if granted {
                        semaphore.signal()
                    } else {
                        semaphore.signal()
                    }
            })
    @unknown default:
        print("unknown")
    }
    print ("\(semaphore.debugDescription)")
}
semaphore.wait()
print ("and we're out")
```

Answer (score 2):

Misusing `DispatchQueue` to force an asynchronous task to become synchronous is a very bad practice.

Either use a completion handler

```
func avAuthorization(completion : @escaping (Bool) -> Void)
{
    let mediaType = AVMediaType.audio
    let mediaAuthorizationStatus = AVCaptureDevice.authorizationStatus(for: mediaType)
    switch mediaAuthorizationStatus {
        case .denied, .restricted: completion(false)
        case .authorized: completion(true)
        case .notDetermined:
            AVCaptureDevice.requestAccess(for: .audio) { granted in
                completion(granted)
            }
    }
}
```

Or in Swift 5.5+ an `async` function

```
func avAuthorization() async -> Bool
{
    let mediaType = AVMediaType.audio
    let mediaAuthorizationStatus = AVCaptureDevice.authorizationStatus(for: mediaType)
    switch mediaAuthorizationStatus {
        case .denied, .restricted: return false
        case .authorized: return true
        case .notDetermined: return await AVCaptureDevice.requestAccess(for: .audio)
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you are already on the main thread and trying to `DispatchQueue.main.sync` from the Main thread. Check it like this.

```
if Thread.isMainThread {
  // you are already on the main thread
} else {
  DispatchQueue.main.sync {
    // do stuff
  }
}
```

Comment: From what I've read you're never supposed to call  DispatchQueue.main.sync, as it will cause a block.

Answer (score 0):

> without waiting for the iOs permission alert to pop up and **complete**

Great line, partially describing possible solution (imho).

AFAIK all `UIAlertController`-related routines are richly flavoured with completions. I'd try to put recording logic trigger inside the completion handler of method that presents the alert itself.

Comment: So if I read you correctly, don't proceed to record part of up, within the completion part of the UIAlertController, when I don't have permissions.

Will take some recoding, but sounds like a plan.